# WSA move apps to secondary drive?

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-android

Is it possible to move or install Windows Subsystem for Android Apps on a different hard drive other than the system drive (C:)?

I'm trying to save space on my local C drive, and I can't seem to find an option to move WSA applications

Comment: Yes; The option to move the entire instance should be within Settings -> Apps & features